# Android Up Navigation

Tags: android, react-native

Can an Android crack maybe help, I try badly on my React Native App to implement a back/close button on my MainActivity.java for a Up Navigation.

([https://developer.android.com/…/implementing…/ancestral.html](https://developer.android.com/%E2%80%A6/implementing%E2%80%A6/ancestral.html))

**MainActivity.java** - will not compile.

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "myapp";
    }
}
```

**Compile Error:**

```
Error:
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
/Users/---/Desktop/myapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/myapp/MainActivity.java:12: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ^
/Users/---/Desktop/myapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/myapp/MainActivity.java:12: error: ';' expected
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                         ^
2 errors
Incremental compilation of 1 classes completed in 0.624 secs.
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

**MainApplication.java**

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.audioStreaming.ReactNativeAudioStreamingPackage;
import com.inprogress.reactnativeyoutube.ReactNativeYouTube;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.pspdfkit.react.PSPDFKitPackage;
import com.geektime.rnonesignalandroid.ReactNativeOneSignalPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new ReactNativeAudioStreamingPackage(),
            new ReactNativeYouTube(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new PSPDFKitPackage(),
            new ReactNativeOneSignalPackage(),
            new ImagePickerPackage(),
            new RNFetchBlobPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
      return "index";
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

My **styles.xml**

```
<resources>
  <style name="myAppTheme" parent="myAppTheme.Base"/>
   <style name="myAppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
  </style>

  <style name="myAppTheme.ExternalTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

So mostly everything is done at react-native and i have no idea how to fix the problem. This posts includes now the entiere MAinActiviy and MainApplication.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

make sure your style.xml has DarkActionbar theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

use instead of

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the statement inside the onCreate Method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: this ends up in:

`…path/MainApplication.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class Bundle
  location: class MainApplication
…path/MainApplication.java:54: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
…path/MainApplication.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ^
  symbol:   method getSupportActionBar()
  location: class MainApplication
3 errors :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED`

Comment: i updated the startpost. Its a react-native project - so the complete MainActiviy and MainApplication is now in the opening post.